# Outputting multiple Session data into a combo box, Why is only one result being produced?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Form which allows me to search a database then display the results into a table, each row has a HTML link 'add' which when clicked takes the row entry and stores it into a session variable for later use.

Another page then attempts to loop through all of the session variables created and output their result into a combo box.

When i add 3 different items i get the session variables:

StockSearchForm1

StockSearchForm2

StockSearchForm3

I use the following code to loop through all session variables and output them one by one into a combo box.

```
echo  '<select  id ="stockDD" name="stockDD" class="stock">';   
    if (isset($_SESSION['isset'])){

if (isset($_SESSION['counts'])){
     $start2 = 0;
     $end2 = $_SESSION['counts'];

           for ($t = $start2; $t < $end2; $t++){
                       foreach ($_SESSION["StockSearchForm$t"] as $option => $value) {
                          echo '<option value='.$value['Part_Number'].'>'.$value['Catagory'].''.$value['Section'].' </option>';

                          print_r($_SESSION["StockSearchForm$t"]);
                          echo '</br>';
                          echo '</br>';
 }
echo '</select>';
```

However my combo box is being created with only one result. Using Print_R gives me the result I would expect, I get the output of each session variable one after another, each containing a row from my database.

Why is it only creating one value in the dropdown box then?

Comment: Can you share the actual output and/or the relevant parts of $_SESSION (count and StockSearchFormN) with us?  There are too many possible problems to make blind guesses at this point.

Comment: Well, I'm going to make one stab without that data... it looks like you have your `echo '</select>';` within the `for` loop when it should be outside of it, so you're closing the tag prematurely.